# Getting database ID for the value of drop down item

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

Disclaimer - yes I googled, clearly I didn't find a solution.

Webform, ASP.NET, SQL, no sqldatasource - all codebehind.

Ok, looks like I was misunderstanding what was going wrong in my application.

Using .SelectedValue does get the correct value of the drop down item - but only in my Insert() method, .SelectedValue returns empty in my UpdateMethod.

Insert()

```
                    using (con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Building(Building_Code, Building_Name, Company_ID, Active) VALUES(@BuildingCode, @BuildingName, @CompanyID, @Active)", con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuildingCode", txtBuildingCode.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuildingName", txtBuildingName.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyID", ddlCompanyCode.SelectedValue);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", chkBuildingActive.Checked);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
```

Update()

```
                    using (con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (ddlCompanyCode.SelectedIndex >= 1)
                        {

                            con.Open();

                            cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Building SET Building_Name = @BuildingName, Company_ID = @CompanyID, Active = @Active WHERE Building_ID = @BuildingID", con);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuildingID", selectedRecordID);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuildingName", txtBuildingName.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyID", ddlCompanyCode.SelectedValue);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", chkBuildingActive.Checked);

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SqlException sqlExc)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(sqlExc.Message);
                    }
                }
```

BindForm()

```
                try
            {
                con.Open();

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    txtBuildingCode.Text = reader["Building_Code"].ToString();
                    txtBuildingName.Text = reader["Building_Name"].ToString();
                    ddlCompanyCode.SelectedItem.Text = reader["Company_Code"].ToString();
                    chkBuildingActive.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Active"));
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlExc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(sqlExc.Message);
            }
```

What would cause this issue?

Comment: @TamásSzabó There is no such property on [DropDownList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: By any chance DropdownList Item's Index matches with the Selected Company_ID ? Code of updating database is executed in SelectedIndexChanged event of DropDownList?

Comment: The ddl index doesn't match on company .  I don't have anything SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: Maybe try to put in both fields the Company_Id, as DataTextField and DataValueField, for debugging and check it out. Do you have duplicates in the Company_Code field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woo!  I got a solution from a friend.

Create a local variable for the company code value

```
        string strCompany = "";
```

Read the contents of the datareader to the variable

```
                            txtBuildingCode.Text = reader["Building_Code"].ToString();
                            txtBuildingName.Text = reader["Building_Name"].ToString();
                            strCompany = reader["Company_Code"].ToString();
```

Then set the SelectedIndex of the drop down to the item index by

```
ddlCompanyCode.SelectedIndex = ddlCompanyCode.Items.IndexOf(ddlCompanyCode.Items.FindByText(strCompany));
```

Thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead using `ddlCompanyCode.DataValueField` use `SelectedValue` property

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyID", ddlCompanyCode.SelectedValue);
```

You can as well use `SelectedItem.Value` like

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyID", ddlCompanyCode.SelectedItem.Value);
```

Comment: .SelectedValue returns the text of the drop down, I need the ID of the value.

Comment: I'm still just geting the text value and not the ID.  When I step into the code I can see that the ddlCompanyCode has an item collection with a count of 5 (which are the records in the company table) but I can't figure out how to access that item number.

Comment: looksl ike I misuderstood what my actual issue was and I've edited my question to reflect that.